# A fake COM port on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, serial

I have a win32 program that communicates via serial port (RS-232 / EIA-232 / COM).
I would like to <strike>intercept</strike> redirect that communication without installing a virtual COM port (filter?) driver like [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/), if possible.
Does Windows provide a feature to redirect these communications (I'm not sure if there's a mechanism like `COPY file.ext con COM1` [not sure of the syntax]?

Answer (score 0):

However, I have to say, I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish by sending a file to a virtual port :/ surely you won't get much more than the actual file back... but...

The point of having a virtual com port is that you can do functions such as redirecting.

I can't really think of an easy way of saying it other than:

Imagine a road that is designed to bend to the right, and you want to redirect everything to the left... it is possible. What you are asking to do is to redirect everything... Without the road!

Personally, I have not done this sort of thing in years, but, the program I used to use is [still around](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hw_vsp/index_en.html) - As for the one you listed, I don't know if it is better or not, again, my knowledge is out of date.

As for Command Prompt Com operations, you can use the `MODE comx` command to configure the port. The full switches are:

```
Serial port:       MODE COMm[:] [BAUD=b] [PARITY=p] [DATA=d] [STOP=s]
                                [to=on|off] [xon=on|off] [odsr=on|off]
                                [octs=on|off] [dtr=on|off|hs]
                                [rts=on|off|hs|tg] [idsr=on|off]
```

As for copying a file, the command will be:

```
copy file.exe com1:
```

Comment: Thank you. The reason for trying to avoid installing a virtual port driver is that I'm in a corporate environment with restricted rights and the need to minimize dependencies.